# Three.js: how to properly apply texture on TorusGeometry

Tags: javascript, three.js, textures, texture-mapping

I'm trying to create a three-dimensional compass, that also displays roll and pitch. In order to show the roll (in degrees), I need to apply a texture with numbers to a TorusMaterial. How can I get it on in such a way that the scale is (somewhat) retained?

The black ring in the picture below (around the compass) is the `TorusGeometry`. The other attached picture is the texture.

Code:

```
var geometry    = new THREE.TorusGeometry(2.41, 0.2, 50, 50);
// var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({ color: 0x000000, wireframe: false });
var material    = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial();
material.map    = THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture('styles/quarters.png');

var torus       = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);

scene.add(torus);
```

Screenshot:
[image: Texture is wrong]

Texture

[image: Texture]